# The image is not re-loaded from Supabase

Tags: angular, supabase

I have such easy function in my Angular app:

```
downloadCategoryPhotoFromSupabase(path: string) {
    this.categoryPhoto = this.supabase.storage
      .from('categories')
      .getPublicUrl(path).data.publicUrl;
  }
```

It is executed every time information about this category is loaded (or updated) into my category unit component.
At the same time, the link in the background-image and the link of the uploaded image to the Network in the browser looks like this:
###.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/categories/0.4668829289505223.png.
However, if I create a category, or update an existing category photo, the image url is updated (and if you click on it, there will be a working image), but the image element itself loses any image source at all (although the background-image) is there and is simply displayed with the background-color of this element.

The updated link has the same kind of path as above, however, it tries to load another one in the Network:
###.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/categories/0.4668829289505223.png

When trying to follow such a link without 'public' I see the following:
`{"statusCode":"400","error":"Error","message":"headers must have required property 'authorization'"}` 
After the page is reloaded, the image loads correctly. Maybe someone have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the image element losing its source after updating the category photo is the way the image URL is being constructed and the timing of the update

Your `<img>` element is trying to load old url, but it fails because image has been moved to new url

This will ensure that the `categoryPhoto` property is updated with the new public URL only after it is available, preventing the `<img>` element from losing its source.

```
downloadCategoryPhotoFromSupabase(path: string) {
  this.supabase.storage
    .from('categories')
    .getPublicUrl(path)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.categoryPhoto = data.data.publicUrl;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is the same before and after the image update, then the cached version is being loaded, which is why you are seeing the same image.

A simple and easy solution for this is to change the URL every time you want to load a new image. You can do so by adding a random query parameter like this:

```js
downloadCategoryPhotoFromSupabase(path: string) {
    const randomString = Date.now()
    this.categoryPhoto = this.supabase.storage
      .from('categories')
      .getPublicUrl(path).data.publicUrl + `?q=${randomString}`;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not actual because my URL changes. I have an answer from Diven Khatri